# React giving me 403 forbidden error when making an API call

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors, http-status-code-403, httpforbiddenhandler

I am using react to switch images using the `Snoowrap` Reddit api wrapper. When I use this function just using Node.js and the app module it works normally:

```
reddit.getSubreddit('pics').getRandomSubmission().then(function(post){
       return(post.url.toString());
     });
```

This is what the function looks like with my normal NodeJS app this code here works 100% fine

```
app.get('/getimage', function(req, res){
  r.getSubreddit(subreddit).getRandomSubmission().then(function(post){
    if(post.url.includes(".jpg") || post.url.includes(".png")){
      res.send(post.url);
      res.end();
    }
    else{
      res.send("No picture extension as .jpg .png")
      console.log("No .jpg Extension");
    }
});
  console.log("Pressed!");
});
```

This code here gives me an unhandled 403 rejection Error I downloaded the chrome browser CORS header extension and it fixed the`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error but now its giving me a 403 error

```
getPic: function() {
     reddit.getSubreddit('pics').getRandomSubmission().then(function(post){
       return(post.url.toString());
     });


   },
```

Comment: did you find the cause & solution to this problem, can you please update here if you remember ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common request that may result in a 403 Forbidden response is a HTTP GET request for a web page **performed by a web browser** to retrieve the page for display to a user in a browser window.

This maybe caused for the CORS extension, if I was you I would try to configure my server as a CORS server instead of using a chrome extension. 
You can use this [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

```
npm install cors --save
```

Before your `app.get(...)` write a `const cors = require('cors')` and `app.use(cors())`

I maybe wrong, but give it a try!